# Find in canvas image in IE 7/8

Tags: javascript, ajax, html5-canvas

Can I use `getImageData()`, in the place of `.toDataURL()`?
If yes, please give me way for using this, because `.toDataURL()` is generating an error for IE 7/8.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using excanvas to support canvas in IE7/8 then

"ExCanvas does not support any of the ImageData functions (createImageData, getImageData, putImageData)."

Please see the discussion at the following link

http://groups.google.com/group/google-excanvas/browse_thread/thread/7d35fa72dbe1487b?pli=1